# How does QML compare two objects when compared with ===?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

My expectation was that, in QML when we compare two objects, it will return true only if they are two same objects. But I am seeing different behavior and that too is not consistent.

To test it, I have the a registered type named `some_type` which is registered using `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` and have a member named `id` of type `QString` -

```
#pragma once
#include <QString>
#include <QMetaType>

struct some_type
{
   QString id;
   some_type() {

   }
   some_type(const some_type &v) : id(v.id) {
   }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(some_type)
```

I have the following model. Its nothing but a property that returns an instance of `some_type` and a invokable method (`sendSomeSignal`) that emits a signal named `sendSomeValueSignal` with an instance of `some_type` as poarameter -

```
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStringList>
#include "some_type.h"

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(some_type someValue READ someValue NOTIFY someValueChanged)

public:
    enum AnimalRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };
    AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    Q_INVOKABLE void sendSomeValue();
    some_type someValue() const;

 signals:
    void sendSomeValueSignal(some_type someValue);
    void someValueChanged();

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QVector<some_type> someValues;
};
```

Here is the implementation of the property constructor, property getter and the invokable method (omitted the rest) -

```
AnimalModel::AnimalModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
    someValues << some_type();
    someValues[0].id = "abcd";

}

some_type AnimalModel::someValue() const {
    return someValues.first();
}

void AnimalModel::sendSomeValue() {
    QString savedStr = someValues.first().id;
    some_type someValue = {};
    someValue.id = savedStr;
    //someValue.id.data();
    emit sendSomeValueSignal(someValue);
}
```

I have the following ListView in qml that does not render any item, when user clicks on the empty listview, model's `sendSomeValue()` method is called which emit the `sendSomeValueSignal` -

```
import QtQuick 2.15
ListView {
    width: 200; height: 250
    required model
    Connections {
        target: model
        function onSendSomeValueSignal(value) {
            var currentValue = model.someValue
            if (value === currentValue) {
                console.log("Same")
            } else {
                console.log("Different")
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            model.sendSomeValue()
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation was that it will always print "Different" because in the `sendSomeValue()` method, I have created a new object. In the `onSendSomeValueSignal()` signal handler, the `value` and `currentValue` are two different objects. By the rule of JavaScript, if the if condition should have returned false.

It looks like, when I compare the two objects of `some_type`, they are compared by the internal `QString` object's allocated heap. I am saying this because if I add the following line, it prints "Different" as the allocated heap has been copied due to calling a non-const method -

```
someValue.id.data();
```

So I am not quite sure how QML is handling this compare. Is there any defined rule that QML follows?

**Please Note:** I am working on another larger project where the behavior is inconsistent. In some cases, the if condition returns `false` even if the internal QString is same for two different `some_type` object. Sometimes, it returns true.

Qt Version: 5.15.2
Compiler: MSVC 2019 64 bit

Comment: QML uses JavaScript, so just look up the rules for JavaScript.

Comment: The behavior isnt consistent with JavaScript it seems.

Comment: @MarkRansom, see the [strict equality description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality). You are talking about rule 1 ("*If the operands are of different types, return false.*") but I think what the OP is talking about is rule 2 ("*If both operands are objects, return true only if they refer to the same object.*") My guess (but I am too lazy to check) is that it would behave as expected by OP if `sendSomeValueSignal` took an object pointer as its argument or possibly a reference but not a straight-up object.

Comment: In any case, passing objects to signals by value, not by reference or as pointers is a nasty practice if you ask me. I am surprised you managed to make that compile (unless it does not compile in fact, I have not tried)...

Comment: @Atmo I have tested with reference and the behavior is exactly same, will confirm with pointer later.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov I am curious about the result; what was it?

Comment: @Atmo Sorry for the delay. The if condition fails in case of pointer even if I return the pointer of the same object (from the someValue method and in sendSomeValueSignal). At this point, the behavior doesnt make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

> My expectation was that, in QML when we compare two objects, it will
> return true only if they are two same objects.

No. Remember that JS is quite loosely typed. The "===" operator merely means the two items being compared are 1) resolve to equal value, and 2) **are of the same type.** Contrast with "==" which returns true if 1) above is true.

**EDIT:** after re-reading the OP's question, I think I better understand what he's asking, and I'm not sure I have an answer. I did try this test:

```
        Component.onCompleted: {
    var var1 = "xxx"
    var var2 = "xxx"
    console.log(var1 === var2)
    const obj1 = {
        key: "xxx"
    };
    const obj2 = {
        key: "xxx"
    };
    console.log(obj1 == obj2)
    console.log(obj1 === obj2)
}
```

and the result came back true, false, false. The 2nd result is particularly puzzling.

Comment: "resolve to equal value" - that seems to be the case for QML, but in case of Javascript, doesnt it has to be the same object for referential types?

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov compare `1=="1"` with `1==="1"`.  That's the difference `===` is meant to capture.

Comment: @MarkRansom The question is not about the difference between '==' and '==='. The question is strictly about the behavior of '===' and if its consistent with JavaScript.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov your statement that `===` means they are the same object implies to me that you don't know how Javascript works either.

Comment: @MarkRansom In case of object , === will return true if both objects are same (unless they are null/undefined which is not the case in my example) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality

If we agree on this, my little example shows different behavior. The if condition evaluates to true even if the two operands are different objects but with same type and same contents.

Comment: @RasheduzzamanSourov the "If both operands are objects" clause surprised me.  I haven't used Javascript much so I hadn't run into it before.  Thinking about it harder, it makes sense because the objects don't have a type beyond "object" so it would be impossible to know if they're the same type.  I'll stop bothering you now.